# Android's default measure unit?

Tags: android, layout

So I noticed now that I'm using everywhere in my layouts "dip" instead of "dp", but for some reason, it worked. Why? Does it fall back to dp? Or what units I was getting?

Comment: dp is the same as dip. You can use both of them. But dp is more similar to sp, so people prefer to use this measure.